# Match on tuples within for comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I am trying to write a function that returns a future. Within this future 3 other future functions are called, the third depends on the results of the first two. My instinct is to use a for comphrension, but when I try to match on the tuple I get this error:

```
value map is not a member of Object
```

Which refers to the match of `(result1, result2)` below

```
def future1 = Future { ... }
def future2 = Future { ... }
def future3(a, b): Future[T] = Future { .... }

def future4: Future[T] = {
  for {
    result1 <- future1
    result2 <- future2
    result3 <- (result1, result2) match {
      case (x, y) => future3(result1, result2)
      case (_, _) => ???
    }
  } yield result3
}
```

Comment: Just move the pattern matching to the `future3` function?

Comment: Yeah that works thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It can be solved by making whatever is under `???` return `Future[T]`